# Deform side-by-side form elements

Tags: python, css, forms, pyramid, deform

Is it possible to render some field side-by-side?

For example, I am using a `SequenceSchema` class with two fields in it. I would like them to render side-by-side. I am looking for something more like a table.

Here is the `SequenceSchema` I would like to *transform*:

```
class SchemaPoint(colander.Schema):
    name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
    min_value = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Float())
    max_value = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Float())


class SchemaPointSeq(colander.SequenceSchema):
    parameters = SchemaParameter()


class SchemaSpace(colander.MappingSchema):
    parameters = SchemaPointSeq()
```

Comment: are you using bootstarp? and please ask a question properly elaboration and show us what you have tried.

Comment: @SumanKalyan I edited the question with some code. It was not really relevant for me as it is some copy from the doc

Comment: Yes. It is called [Retail Form Rendering](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/retail.html).